# KDE Plasma 5 on Fedora 22 - clicking desktop link to .odt (or .doc) file fails to launch OpenOffice

Tags: fedora, kde, openoffice

Recently this started happening for no apparent reason: If I click a desktop link to a .odt or .doc file (and presumably others), I get a warning dialog that says:

```
This will start the program
openoffice4 -writer %U
If you do not trust this program, click cancel
```

If I click "continue", then I get a dialog with this error message:

```
Unable to make the service OpenOffice 4.1.1 Writer executable, aborting execution
```

This was working fine for a year or so, and only just suddenly start showing this behavior.  I didn't make any changes that I can think of, that should affect this.  The googling I've done to date doesn't turn up anything helpful either.

Any idea on how to resolve this? If it helps, I can start openoffice just fine from the command line, and Iv'e confirmed that the program files in /opt/openoffice4 (like swriter, etc) have the executable bit set.  And the current user is the owner of those files as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I still don't understand exactly *what* happened, or why, but I did find a cure for this.  On a hunch, I ran kmenuedit, and navigated to the "Office" section, and edited each of the application icons for each of the individual AOO apps.  In particular, I replaced things like "openoffice4 -calc %U" with "/usr/bin/openoffice4 -calc %U", and then saved each one.   This fixed the problem of clicking on .odt files and launching AOO.   It did not however, make the icons saved as "Favorites" in the KDE application launcher work.  But after I removed each of them from "Favorites" and re-added them, they worked again.

So, basically, I suspect *something* got corrupted and re-saving the launcher links in kmenuedit updated the "something" and resolved the problem.  But I don't know enough about how KDE works to appreciate exactly what was going on.